# React routing - Routes independent of parent routing files

Tags: reactjs, routes

I am defining the routes in react

Global ones in the app-routes.js file and other in their respective components.

**app.js**

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="App-wrap">
    <AppRoutes/>
  </div>
); }
```

**app-route.js**

```
export class AppRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={LayoutComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

**layout-component.js**

I have placed my header here for navigation

```
    export class LayoutComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LayoutWrap>
        <HeaderComponent> </HeaderComponent>
        <LayoutRoutes />
      </LayoutWrap>
    );
  }
}
```

**layout.routing.js**

```
    export class LayoutRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Switch>
          <Route  path="/" exact >
          <Redirect to="/users"/>
          </Route>
          <Route  path="/users"  name="Users" component={UserComponent} />
          <Route  path="/permissions"  name="Permissions"  component={PermissionComponent} />
        </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Now the issue is, when i am defining my child routes, my child routes are dependent on parent 
i.e. i have to write parent's previous url in child.
If i change my app-routes.js path from "" to layout my routing will not work.

```
<Route path="/layout" component={LayoutComponent} />
```

How to solve the issue?

Comment: What is the issue here? You're nesting your routes, so this is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining your child Routes, you need to prefix the parent route path before it for these to work. For this you can make use of `match.path` from props like

```
export class LayoutRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    return (
        <Switch>
          <Route  path={match.path} exact render ={(props) => <Redirect to="/users"/>} />
          <Route  path=`${match.path}/users`  name="Users" component={UserComponent} />
          <Route  path=`${match.path}/permissions` name="Permissions"  component={PermissionComponent} />
        </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```